# Mirroring harddisk with compressed files with Robocopy

Tags: ntfs, compression, robocopy, mirroring

I tried to mirroring an existing disks on a new disks with less space. It is very important that the file structure, attributes and ACL's are exact as on the source disk.

For this I tried `robocopy.exe`:

```
robocopy $sourceDisk $destinationDisk /mir /XD "System Volume Information" "`$RECYCLE.BIN" /copyall /r:1 /NP /NFL
```

That command copies all folders and files with attributes, ACL's, etc. over to the destination disk, except for the *compress*-attribute, i.e. files or folders which are compressed on the source disk are on the destination disk not longer compressed. This attribute is missing.

Is there an option for robocopy to do this (I didn't find it). Or are there existing other approaches to make an exact copy of an disk or file structure to another disk?

Comment: What operating system is this - I'm assuming some version of Windows. Isn't compression a feature of the file system - sounds like you've not turned on compression on the destination disk.

Comment: @PaulHaldane it is a Windows 7/2008 machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to manage this problem with the commandline tool `strarc.exe` from [LTR-Data](http://www.ltr-data.se/).

This tool copies the files, as far as I understand, on a lower layer than robocopy. All attributes, ACL's are exact on the destination like the source - even the timestamps. The junctions where also correct copied.

The command is

```
$srcDisk = "Y:"
$dstDisk = "Z:"
cmd /c "C:\temp\strarc.exe -cjd:$srcDisk | C:\temp\strarc -s:8 -xd:$dstDisk"
```

It makes a copy of the `$srcDisk`, i.e. Y: to `$dstDisk`, i.e. Z: including junctions and ignoring messages about 8.3 compability (`-s:8`).

I recommend this tool for exact backups via commandline.

Comment: Fantastic tool! Very strange that no one else has a solution for this problem.

Answer (score 2):

I am not aware of any version of `robocopy` that supports copying the Compressed attribute. (I just tested with the version that ships with Windows Server 2012 R2 just to be sure that a version newer than my Windows 7 laptop still did not include this behavior.)

If you're going to use `robocopy` you'll need to script something to follow-up behind it compressing files/folders that require compression. (I could imagine some kind of script that would use `robocopy` with the the `/ia` command-line argument to copy only compressed files first, compress all the copied-files, then run `robocopy` again using the `/xa` argument to copy the non-compressed files.)

In terms of copying the "exact structure" of the disk, a sector-for-sector copy would be the way to go. A tool like [`dd`](http://www.chrysocome.net/dd) will let you do sector-for-sector copying of volumes.

If your definition of "exact structure" is less rigorous and you're just looking for an exact copy of the directory structure, file data, attributes (including compression), and ACLs I'd look at a disk-imaging tool. Microsoft's [ImageX](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc722145%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) tool is one example. (You can obtain ImageX from Microsoft inside various packages-- the Windows Automated Installation kit contains a copy and, I believe, it's also included in Windows Deployment Services). There are lots of third-party tools would fit the bill, too.

Comment: There's a thread here suggesting the same thing (copy files and then re-apply the file compression).  Includes powershell to accomplish same: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/63bb43b4-1cbb-4859-83e7-f17b9ac01cd9/robocopy-file-compression-attribute

Comment: @BlueCompute - I'd just copy the compressed files first using `robocopy` with the `/ia` command-line argument, run a `for` loop to `compact` all the files in the destination directory, then run a second `robocopy` with the `/xa` argument to copy the non-compressed files. That leaves the job of detecting which files are compressed to `robocopy`. This is still sub-optimal because it results in decompression and recompression of the files, but I'm not sure that NTFS gives `robocopy` any way to copy the file in the compressed state anyway.

Comment: Ah yes that makes sense.  I skimmed your original answer and missed that logic :-(

Comment: @EvanAnderson `dd` does not work, because I copy from a bigger disk to a smaller one. The filesystem is afterwards not accessible. Fixing the partition table is not possible, because the disks are virtual disks managed by `imdisk.exe`. Robocopy and ImageX approach, which you mentioned I didn't test. I was able to manage the problem with `strarc.exe`.

Comment: Note quite automatic but I handled this by doing robocopy once with the /CREATE flag, which creates the directory tree and zero-length files. Then, I did the compression by hand (picking out select folders to compress at the destination based on what was set up at the source). Then I did robocopy again without the /CREATE flag and it copied over all of the data. Folders and files that were compressed already retained their compression. This would work if you have a pretty good idea where the compressed files and folders are. If I ever have to do this again, I will probably try the strarc tool.